# Android Activity restoring state automatically

Tags: android, android-activity

In my app I haven't overridden any state related methods like `onPause()`, `onStop()` but still my activity is restoring its previous state automatically in some device but in others device it's not restoring.

Why is this happening?

Here is the code:

```
 new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
      mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     mTextField.setText("done!");
 }
}.start();
```

Comment: What have you done, show some code..

Comment: @HarishKoona Its happening to all the activity.Which code should I show you?

Comment: @HarishKoona I have added a code kindly check and reply

Answer (score 1):

This is all described in [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) part of Android developer guide.

> By default, the system uses the Bundle instance state to save information about each View object in your activity layout (such as the text value entered into an EditText object). So, if your activity instance is destroyed and recreated, the state of the layout is restored to its previous state with no code required by you.

So it means that the state of the views is saved automatically. It doesn't happen all the time though, for example:

> When your activity is destroyed because the user presses Back or the activity finishes itself, the system's concept of that Activity instance is gone forever because the behavior indicates the activity is no longer needed.

Comment: yes its doing the same as you said but in some others phone its not working even when the home button is pressed or during a incoming call.

Comment: Does that depend on the Android version or something else in common?

Comment: Is it not restoring automatically on older versions? I have this hunch that it didn't do it before but I can't find anything about it at the moment...

Answer (score 0):

If you press Home button and then open your application, your application will be restored and timer will work from related place (when you press Home button - application works in background). But if you press Back button (application is finished) and then open application - it will be recreated/restarted and timer will start from beginning.

Comment: In my phone its working fine,but in some other phone if I press the home button or a call is coming then the timer is not working...